# Javascript - focus/jump on anchor link to behave the same in all browsers (plus maybe add hash # to link)

Tags: javascript

I have a simple Javascript function that should take/focus user to the exact hash link location on page. The problem is - it behaves differently on different browsers (it seems to work best in Firefox and worst in Chrome / Opera) AND it actually doesn't take user to the the exact anchor position.

It would be best that after clicking on the button user is always taken to the exact anchor link location (ie. from the example it would be: .../UfDLW/16/show/#2). And after clicking on the link user should always be 'taken' to the top of the page, ie. the focused link #2 should be right on top of the page (currently it positions randomly somehow).

Perhaps a solution would be to 'force' browser to add the #2 to the link at the time on clicking on the button, but not sure how to do it and if it's the right solution.

```
<button type="button" onclick="focusHash();">FOCUS</button>

<div style="height:500px"><a id="a1" href="#1">#1</a></div>

<div style="height:500px"><a id="a2" href="#2">#2</a></div>

<div style="height:500px"><a id="a3" href="#3">#3</a></div>


function focusHash() {
document.getElementById('a2').focus();
}
```

Here is jfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/pdXEt/3/

I can only use pure Javascript here (no JQuery).

Comment: Don't have alternate browsers to test it so I won't post as an answer, but you could try `document.location.hash = "2";`

Comment: User must be taken to the EXACT location of the anchor, for example when you click on this link with your comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24498301/javascript-focus-jump-on-anchor-link-to-behave-the-same-in-all-browsers-plus#comment37925225_24498301 your comment is on top of the page (ie. you are taken to top of the page to read the comment).

Answer (score 1):

`focus` doesn't move the browser window except to make the element visible. If you want it to behave the same as clicking the link, you need to modify the URL to include the correct hash fragment for the anchor tag you which to move to.

Here's a version that accepts an ID, focuses the element, and then moves to it by setting `window.location.hash`:

```
function focusHash(id) {
  document.getElementById(id).focus();
  window.location.hash = id;
}
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/pdXEt/9/

Comment: I updated it here: http://jsfiddle.net/pdXEt/5/ - but you're still not taken to the #2? After clicking the #2 link should be right on top of the window...

Comment: @Gooden I didn't understand the question; see updated answer. You're missing the window.location.hash =...` part.

Comment: Thanks - looks good :) - but what does it mean: match(/#\d+/)[0] -- is it going to work correctly in all browsers (ie. isn't it some kind of dirty hack that may stop working in the future? :)

Comment: I'm not sure why you need all of that.  If you are trying to move to the element with `id` of `2` then the hash should just be `2`.  What's idea behind the regex?

Comment: @JamesMontagne The `href` for the link will be `http://www.example.com/#2`. I only want the `#2`. I'm assuming this function is meant to be generic enough to work with other links, so I didn't hard-code the hash fragment.

Comment: Yes, it's generic function that is supposed to work with multiple #X on the page. So it's good one?

Comment: But if you're trying to move to the element all you need is the `id`.  So `el.id` instead of regex.  (assuming you didn't get it by id to begin with)

Comment: @JamesMontagne Ah, I see what you mean. I was confused by the fact that the anchor tags are self-referential. Yes, we could just use `el.id`, unless the actual intent of the question is to focus the element the anchor tag points to.

Comment: meagar, so could you please post the second function too (I don't know how to use el.id), thanks..

Comment: @Gooden See update. What confused me is that you've made each link's href point to *itself*, and I was "following" that link. If you just want the link to be an anchor point within the page, you don't need an `href`, you only need an `id` or `name`.

Comment: @Gooden If your only intent is to scroll the page you can get rid of the `focus` line completely as well.